# Combine count result to join in laravel

Tags: mysql, laravel-5, lumen-5.2

i want get something like list of news with number of comment

article ------------- comment
news1 ---------------- 10
news2 ---------------- 2
news3 ---------------- 13
news4 ---------------- 25

i know how to do it with raw sql but can't make it with laravel. laravel can handle raw query but i don't want to use it for the whole query.
here is my current snipped code:

```
$newslist = News::where('status_id', 2)->orderBy('id', 'desc')->skip(0)->take($itemPerLoad)
        ->join('msuser', 'msuser.id', '=', 'news.user_id')
        ->select(....)->get();
```

i have tried put count on select method but got error (with join comment table as not written above)

```
->select('news.id', 'count(mscomment.id) as commented', ...)
```

because i can't join it, currently i use separate code to count it and set it to json response

```
$commented = Comment::where('news_id', $news->id)->count();
```

i think its not good way to get the number because it will request count for each loop

Comment: Have you tried using **selectRaw** like this: `->selectRaw('news.id', 'count(mscomment.id) as commented', ...)`.

Comment: it give me this error:    Argument 2 passed to Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::selectRaw() must be of the type array, string given

Comment: Sorry, this is my mistake. Pass all the columns in a single string like this: `->selectRaw('news.id, count(mscomment.id) as commented')`.

Comment: count() method working but in my case for now i prefer huuk answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Eloquent [relations](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many)

**News.php**

```
public function comments()
{
    return $this->hasMany('NAMESPACE_TO_YOUR_MODEL\Comment');
}
```

Then in Controller

```
$news = News::with('comments')->get();
$summary = [];
foreach($news as $n)
{
    $summary[] = ['article' =>$n->article, 'comments' => $n->comments->count()];
}
```

or you can iterate in view:

```
@foreach($news as $n)
    <tr>
        <td> {{ $n->article }} </td>
        <td> {{ $n->>comments->count() }} </td>
    </tr>
@endforeach
```

I think this way is canonical

Comment: this working good as needed. also make me notice about eloquent-relationships feature. thank you